# Restart Sharepoint Management Shell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I would like to know if it is possible to restart Sharepoint Management Shell, so that i can reload a new App Domain ?

Comment: it is ok, i found it, just using : Powershell.exe -File script.ps1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is ok, i found it, just using : Powershell.exe -File script.ps1